# mod rewrite problem?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am facing a problem using mod_rewrite. This is what I am using

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule pc/$ /pc.php
```

to rewrite *http://www.example.com/pc/* to *http://www.example.com/pc.php*.
This is working perfectly fine but, when I go to a domain such as *http://www.example.com/news/today-in-pc/* it is showing the *pc.php* page.
What am I doing wrong here and how can I eliminate this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to anchor the match to the start of the URL:

```
# If you're using .htaccess
RewriteRule ^pc/$ /pc.php

# If you're using httpd.conf
RewriteRule ^/pc/$ /pc.php
```